# How to return DML statements results from Bigquery with python (Update, Delete)?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm running DML commands with Python3 and bigquery (using google-cloud-bigquery package).
Compared to results provided by running the command in the console, I can't get it with Python.

Running the normal:

```py
client = bigquery.Client()
result = client.query(...).result()
```

How can I read results for delete and update statements?

[image]

Comment: I proposed you an answer, can you check it please and mark it as solved if it helped you to solve your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a field called `query_job.num_dml_affected_rows` for that in the [BigQuery Python client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-update-with-dml#bigquery_update_with_dml-python) :

```py
import pathlib
from typing import Dict, Optional

from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.bigquery import enums


def load_from_newline_delimited_json(
    client: bigquery.Client,
    filepath: pathlib.Path,
    project_id: str,
    dataset_id: str,
    table_id: str,
) -> None:
    full_table_id = f"{project_id}.{dataset_id}.{table_id}"
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.source_format = enums.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
    job_config.schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField("id", enums.SqlTypeNames.STRING),
        bigquery.SchemaField("user_id", enums.SqlTypeNames.INTEGER),
        bigquery.SchemaField("login_time", enums.SqlTypeNames.TIMESTAMP),
        bigquery.SchemaField("logout_time", enums.SqlTypeNames.TIMESTAMP),
        bigquery.SchemaField("ip_address", enums.SqlTypeNames.STRING),
    ]

    with open(filepath, "rb") as json_file:
        load_job = client.load_table_from_file(
            json_file, full_table_id, job_config=job_config
        )

    # Wait for load job to finish.
    load_job.result()


def update_with_dml(
    client: bigquery.Client, project_id: str, dataset_id: str, table_id: str
) -> int:
    query_text = f"""
    UPDATE `{project_id}.{dataset_id}.{table_id}`
    SET ip_address = REGEXP_REPLACE(ip_address, r"(\\.[0-9]+)$", ".0")
    WHERE TRUE
    """
    query_job = client.query(query_text)

    # Wait for query job to finish.
    query_job.result()

    assert query_job.num_dml_affected_rows is not None

    print(f"DML query modified {query_job.num_dml_affected_rows} rows.")
    return query_job.num_dml_affected_rows
```

Comment: I don't receive that field when calling query from the client class.